# Why Office E3 365 for Developer only extends one day?

Tags: officedev

Today my office 365 E3 for developer get auto renewed. but it only extends one day, from 2019.9.17 to 2019.9.18

How often will the Office 365 developer renewable subscription get renewed? Some of my friends get renewed every 5-6 months but last time my subscription extended 2 months and this time only 1 day.

Is it a bug of Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your comment. This is not correct behavior and I'm sorry you experienced this. If you got this from the Office 365 Developer Program it should be renewed for 3 months. Not one day.

Comment: You can read the documentation here on the correct behavior for Office 365 Developer Subscription renewal here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/subscription-expiration-and-renewal

Comment: I report this in github and this is a bug of the renewal program.